# Plugin Knapsack error on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, knapsack-problem, elasticsearch-plugin

I tried to install the plugin "knapsack" on elasticsearch,
but in my log I see the error

```
    [2015-10-20 09:12:49,739][WARN ][plugins                  ] [yt1] plugin knapsack, failed to invoke custom onModule method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService.processModule(PluginsService.java:200)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsModule.processModule(PluginsModule.java:61)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.Modules.processModules(Modules.java:64)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ModulesBuilder.createInjector(ModulesBuilder.java:58)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode.<init>(InternalNode.java:197)
    at org.elasticsearch.node.NodeBuilder.build(NodeBuilder.java:159)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:70)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:203)
    at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class org.xbib.elasticsearch.action.RestExportAction overrides final method handleRequest.(Lorg/elasticsearch/rest/RestRequest;Lorg/elasticsearch/rest/RestChannel;)V
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.xbib.elasticsearch.knapsack.KnapsackPlugin.onModule(KnapsackPlugin.java:40)
    ... 13 more
```

when I try to export a index it states:

```
{"error":"MapperParsingException[failed to parse, document is empty]","status":400}
```

Do you have any idea of how to solve this error? Unfortunately I did not find a solution on Google.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

ok, I've found the answer myself.

You need the same version of elasticsearch and knapsack